# HTML how to link CSS in another directory?

Tags: html, css

The structure of my current public_html is as follows:
[image: My CSS is in the "css" directory, while my php/html is in the "register" directory.]

Snippet:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">`

The HTML is in the "register" directory.

Any help?

Comment: If `main.css` is in the `css` folder it should work if the public_html is the document root.

Comment: main.css is infact in the CSS folder, yet it doesn't work

Comment: Use relative references, they are more portable anyway: `../css/main.css`

Comment: move the html out side register folder or use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">`

Comment: @JaredChu that won't work if the HTML is page is located in the site root or a grandchild subdirectory. I'm assuming OP is using a templating system where the same HTML for importing stylesheets appears in multiple files.

Comment: How do you access your site? Is it something like `www.example.com/register/index.html`?

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: @KodosJohnson https://www.example.com/register

Comment: Ok then it should work. Based on one of your comments below, I think it might be a `.htaccess` rewriting issue.

Answer (score 5):

To go one directory up you type

`../`

So in this case the solution is simply:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">`

---

You can link to the stylesheet absolutely:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/main.css" />`

or

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/main.css" />`

or by using `base href ~`:

`<base href="http://example.com/" />`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />`

Comment: https://www.vobern.com/register/ is the content that should be affected.

Comment: Sure. In the html, just substitute your snippet `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">` with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">`. LMK how it went.

Comment: Glad it worked! :) Please accept the best answer. You get 2 points when you accept an answer (and you can wait as long as you like to do that). [Here's an image on how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)

Comment: Ups forgot to mention you @astral.

Answer (score 1):

Using `/css/main.css` will always work because the leading `/` means the path is interpreted as a site-root-relative path. You don't need to change anything.

If you had just `css/main.css` then it would only work for documents in the site's root, because the path is by-default interpreted as being relative to the current location, so...

Relative:

```
http://mywebsite.com/foobar.html + "css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/css/main.css

http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory/foobar.html + "css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory/css/main.css
```

Root-relative:

```
http://mywebsite.com/foobar.html + "/css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/css/main.css

http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory/foobar.html + "/css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/css/main.css
```

Relative reference:

```
http://mywebsite.com/foobar.html + "../css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/main.css

http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory/foobar.html + "../css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/css/main.css

http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory/anothersub/foobar.html + "../css/main.css" -> http://mywebsite.com/subdirectory/css/main.css
```

Comment: @astral Please post the **rendered** HTML in your question. Are you using purely static HTML files, any kind of URI rewriting or templating system?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I do have my .htaccess redirecting to the https version of the domain, but this was never an issue before.

Comment: @astral check your browser's F12 tools' Network tab to see where the request for the CSS file ultimately resolves to.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this dude:**

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm so stupid. It turns out my cache was outdated.

Thank you all for the help.